# Fiscal Year to Date filter

Tags: oracle, optimization, date

This is my data:

[image]

I need a Fiscal Year to Date logic that will gather all previous months starting October.
However, for October 2018 I want to start form 15th, for remaining years it must start from October 1st.

Expected result would be all dates from October till last day of previous month.
For testing purpose I replaced `sysdate, 'MM'` with `to_date('31-DEC-18'), 'MM'`

Below is working but wondering if I can improve it...

```
PER_PERIOD_START_DATE between 

(CASE
WHEN (a.PER_MONTH_NUM = 10 and extract( year from a.PER_PERIOD_START_DATE) = 2018)
THEN Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(to_date('31-DEC-19'),6),'YYYY'),-3) +14
ELSE Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(to_date('31-DEC-19'),6),'YYYY'),-3) 
END
)
and trunc(to_date('31-DEC-19'), 'MM')-1
```

Final code:

```
where PER_PERIOD_START_DATE between 

(CASE
WHEN (PER_MONTH_NUM = 10 and extract( year from PER_PERIOD_START_DATE) = 2018)
THEN Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,6),'YYYY'),-3) + 14
ELSE Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,6),'YYYY'),-3) 
END
)
and trunc(sysdate, 'MM')-1
```

Comment: Where do `PER_PERIOD_START_DATE` and `PER_PERIOD_TYPE` come from? Your table has only one column.

Comment: Better use date literal `DATE '2018-12-31'` or specify the format like `TO_DATE('31-DEC-18', 'DD-MON-RR', 'nls_date_language = american')`

Comment: What is the purpose of `trunc (to_date('31-DEC-18'), 'MM') - interval '1' month`? Just write `DATE '2018-11-01'`

Answer (score 0):

Below code fully meets the requirement:

```
PER_PERIOD_START_DATE between 

(CASE
WHEN (PER_MONTH_NUM = 10 and extract( year from PER_PERIOD_START_DATE) = 2018)
THEN Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,3),'YYYY'),-3) + 14
ELSE Add_Months(Trunc(Add_Months(sysdate,3),'YYYY'),-3) 
END
)
and trunc(sysdate, 'MM')-1
```

Alternative:

```
PER_PERIOD_START_DATE between 

(CASE
WHEN (PER_MONTH_NUM = 10 and extract( year from PER_PERIOD_START_DATE) = 2018)
THEN '15-OCT-'||(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -9)))
ELSE '01-OCT-'||(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -9)))
END
)
and trunc(sysdate, 'MM')-1
```